Pod: should the section part in a Pod link include formatting codes?
A hopefully simple question which I haven't been able to find an answer to: should the section part of a Pod link include formatting codes in the section heading linked to like in L<<< Foo::Bar/"C<< foo => $bar >>" >>> or should you omit them like in L<< Foo::Bar/"foo => $bar" >>?
I haven't been able to either find or contrieve a scenario where it actually matters, at least when generating URLs with the usual converters.

Have you found any such link in MetaCPAN?

I adopted a style that makes the issue moot.

The L<> creates links to other content, so other interior sequences are probably not appropriate in them. Code examples in them are likely inappropriate. In your examples, the problematic characters probably end up in a named anchor, which can just be ignored by the user-agent.
On the other side, I tend to not use any interior sequences in headings, but then I tend to not put code-like things in headings.
